# What difference does it make which version of Mozilla, MacOS and Safari we specify for using ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, macos-catalina

I came across this snippet of code for downloading m3u8 playlists and concatenating them into an mkv file:

```
$ ffmpeg -user_agent "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/537.86.7" -i https://devstreaming-cdn.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2019/901myoscpux9y7nry55/901/hls_vod_mvp.m3u8 -c copy pd.mkv
```

My question is about the section of the script:

```
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/601.7.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/9.1.3 Safari/537.86.7"
```

These seem like very old numbers. For example, Catalina is 10.15.3. No idea which is the latest Mozilla but Safari is now on 13.0.5

Was just wondering if it makes any difference if the version is old, or if we should update to the code to specify newer versions of Mac OS, Mozilla, Webkit and Safari.

Can someone explain the significance ?

Answer (score 1):

You should google “user agent” to see exactly what it is used for.

Ffmpeg does not do anything with that value. It just sends to to the server as an http header. The server may or may not do anything with it. Its not required 99.999% of the time. Some servers will give a different response depending on the user agent to prevent web site scraping, but again, that’s rare.  If you remove it, ffmpeg will probably still work and produce identical output.

Comment: I guess since we’re using it to request an m3u8 file, it just doesn’t matter what browser it is?

Comment: Probably? But I don’t control apple.com so I can’t guarantee anything.

Comment: Noooo...way.... srs? I thought u controlled evrything... braaaaaaah!!!! 